# Add remove html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create a form to add multiple images with caption . As I m php and mysql person. So if i could get new fields on clicking addmore then i can do the rest php mysql part.
How can i set var x to create a new row to provide new browse button and caption textfield.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function addMore() {
if (document.getElementById && document.createElement) {
    var x = ;
    document.getElementById('inserthere').appendChild(x);
}
else alert('Your browser doesn\'t support the Level 1 DOM');
}

function delMore() {
if (document.getElementById && document.createElement) {
    var node = document.getElementById('inserthere')
    node.removeChild(node.childNodes[0]);
}
else alert('Your browser doesn\'t support the Level 1 DOM');
}
// -->
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Select Image<input type="file" name="img[]" id="img"  /></td><td>Add caption
<input type="text" name="img_cap[]" id="img_cap" /></td>
</tr>
<span id="inserthere"></span>
</table>

<a href="javascript:addMore()" class="page">add More</a><br />
<a href="javascript:delMore()" class="page">remove</a>

</body>
```

Till someone replies i am going to learn , explore internet and try try try.....

Comment: This will help you http://jsfiddle.net/JV8eU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest way but the simplest, quickest way is probably to give the table an `id` property (say, for example, `'imgtable'`), and do the following in your `addMore()` function:

```
var x = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row ready to add
x.innerHTML = '<td>Select Image<input type="file" name="img[]" id="img"  /></td><td>Add caption <input type="text" name="img_cap[]" id="img_cap" /></td>'; // fill it with your code
document.getElementById('imgtable').appendChild(x) // add the new row to the table
```

As you want to learn more though, be sure to look up methods like `document.createDocumentFragment()` as a way of appending individually declared elements to an object before you actually add it to the DOM. The `innerHTML` method I have used can be quicker but it's not as neat and can be more difficult to debug than declaring a document fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THank you ....... it is working plus i understood it also. I will now work on remove row on click on cross button .... lets see ...

Comment: But for remove it is removing all , i want to have aleast 1 row remaining or can we somehow count number of child node and set if condition?